# Recursive Descent Parser Details

Tags: java

I've been tasked to develop a Recursive Descent Parser for a specific Grammar.

The language I am parsing for essentially just adds "" to the beginning and end of an argument. For example, the following input:

```
start 'Begin' { top { text {Top of the world} } }
```

Would output:

```
<start> Begin <top> Top of the world </top> </start>
```

So here's where I am at with the Parser thus far:

```
public String parser(String s){
    StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
    String output="";
    try {
        while (st.nextToken() != st.TT_EOF){
            if (st.ttype == st.TT_WORD){
                if (st.sval.equals("start")){
                    st.nextToken(); 
                    if (st.nextToken() == '\''){
                        //I need to get the remaining string that 
                        //we haven't parsed yet to recursively call parser on it.
                        return "<start>" + st.sval + parser(??) + "</start>";
                    }
                }
                if (st.sval.equals("top")){
                     //Need to get remaining string again
                     return "<top> " + parser(??) + " </top> ";
                }
                if (st.sval.equals("text")){
                    st.nextToken();
                    if (st.nextToken() == '{'){
                        //I need to capture everything inside the curly braces
                        String inside = //Everything inside the curly braces
                        return inside;
                    }
                }
         }
    }catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

So as you can see, I am having difficulty with the following:

- Getting the remaining String after we've removed a token. We need this so we can recursively parse the entire String.
- Detecting and capturing everything inside of curly braces.

I believe I have the form and flow of a Recursive Descent Parser down, but if I am mistaken in anything please don't hesitate to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parser should have a signature `public String parser(StringTokenizer st)`, then you can simply pass the tokenizer when recursing (keep in mind that after recursing the current token will be incorrect). Then you can just write `return "<top> " + parser(st) + " </top> ";`. Lastly, add another clause that activates on curly open brace, which returns a concatenation of all the tokens up to and including the close brace.

TBH it would help if you also copied the grammar here...

Comment: Tassos, thank you for your suggestion on passing StreamTokenizer as a parameter and not just the String, brilliant! That saves me from having to play with indexes and substrings. I'm still stuck on how to concatenate tokens between two curly braces though. Is this a situation where I would want to locate the closing brace and then substring it?

Comment: Depends on if you want to preserve whitespace: if you do not, just have a mode of the parser (could be a separate method) that takes begins on just past the brace (the last token that was received from the tokenizer) and proceeds to concatenate all received tokens up to the closing brace (take note to recursively call this method if you want sub-braces). If you need to preserve white space, you're in a world of hurt and you will need to implement back-and forth between String and StringTokenizer...